# Oracle ref cursor / normal cursor at schema level

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, sys-refcursor, ref-cursor

I am wondering if we can declare a `cursor` or a `ref cursor` at schema level as stored objects. I tried using the below statement for `ref cursor`

```
CREATE TYPE my_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURNING employees%ROWTYPE;
```

But I got error. A small working example would do and if we cannot then a brief on reason behind it will be a great help.

Comment: Can you please explain as in why do you try to use `TYPE my_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN employees%ROWTYPE` ? What is the object which you want to achieve as using a weak refcursor is anyhow discouraged in Oracle. It seems you want to achieve the functioanlity of `sys_refcursor` then why not directly using it ?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible. From [CREATE TYPE Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375):

> The CREATE TYPE statement creates or replaces the specification of one of these:
>
> - Abstract Data Type (ADT) (including a SQLJ object type)
> - Standalone varying array (varray) type
> - Standalone nested table type
> - Incomplete object type

Comment: hmm.. then i guess the only way left to do it is via a package having declaration for all ref cursors.

Comment: I have given examle in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE yourSchemaName.yourPackageName AS
TYPE my_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN employees%ROWTYPE;
--your stored procedure and function declarations 
end yourPackageName ;
```

This is working example in oracle sql. This is package specification and ref cursor type declaration in it;